# (Python) How to join two existing clusters if an additional element links the two?

Tags: python, set, cluster-computing, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

What I need to do is to first generate a set of coordinates randomly, and if the points' coordinates are close enough, then they are connected and form 'cluster'. Suppose that the connection of the points is as follow:

```
graph = {'A': set(['B', 'C']),
         'B': set(['A', 'D', 'E']),
         'C': set(['A', 'F']),
         'D': set(['B']),
         'E': set(['B', 'F']),
         'F': set(['C', 'E']),
         'G': set(['H','I']),
         'H': set(['G']),
         'I': set(['J']),
         'J': set(['I'])}
```

And I have the following code for finding the 'cluster' formed among the points:

```
def BFS(graph, node, visited=None):
    if visited is None:
        visited = set()
    print 'Visiting', node
    visited.add(node)
    for next in graph[node]:
        if next not in visited:
            BFS(graph, next, visited)
    return visited
def List_of_Cluster(graph): 
    n=len(graph)
    c=set(np.arange(n))
    cluster_list=[] 
    while c:    
        i=c.pop()   
        temp = BFS(graph,i) 
        cluster_list +=[temp]  
        c -= temp   
    return cluster_list
```

So I will end up with two clusters [set(['A','B','C','D','E','F']),set(['G','H','I','J'])]

Everything works well for me. But now suppose I have an additional point K: set(['E','I']), which happen to be a member of some existing clusters, and in this case, it actually joins the two clusters to form a new bigger cluster. Instead of running the whole program from the beginning with the the point K added to the dictionary 'graph', what can I do? How can I check the connection of point K with the existing clusters and add K directly to them (or even join some existing clusters to form a bigger one)? Since I will need to keep adding new coordinates (probably over one thousand), I want to write the code in a better way for the speed for running the program can be faster as well.

Thanks

Comment: Silly question, but where is 'a' initialized? And, what are you using 'c' for?

Comment: just a typo (already corrected). there is only c (for storing all the points that have not been checked by BFS) but no a. Sorry if my question sounds silly, but I would much appreciate it if someone can offer some help to such a stupid person like me, so hopefully I don't have to ask anymore more silly questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from your example that for any `X` and `Y`, if `X in graph[Y]` then `Y in graph[X}`.  If that's the case, then:

```
def addNode(name, neighbors, graph, clusterlist):
    graph[name] = neighbors
    clusters = set()
    for n in neighbors:
        graph[n].add(name)
        for c in clusterlist:
            if n in c:
                c.add(name)
                clusters.add(frozenset(c))
    if len(clusters) > 1:
        bigcluster = set(clusters.pop())
        for c in clusters:
            bigcluster.update(c)
        new_clusterlist = [c for c in clusterlist if name not in c]
        new_clusterlist.append(bigcluster]
        clusterlist[:] = new_clusterlist
```

You could and probably should add many edge-case checks (are all nodes claimed as neighbors of the new one existing, is the name actually a new one, etc, etc) but I believe this should be roughly the logic to do what you require.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [disjoint-set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) data structure. The disjoint-set is specifically for storing and merging sets. It supports two operations: UNION, which joins two sets, and FIND, which finds which set a node belongs to.

For your problem, whenever you read a new node, create a new set for it and merge (UNION) it with all of the nodes connected to it. To print the sets, you need to iterate over all the nodes and group them together according to their set.

Answer (score 1):

I would try treating the new node(s) as a new graph, then running your existing code on it. This will give you two cluster lists. Now, you can treat the merging of the cluster lists as a new problem.

Consider merging a single new cluster with an existing cluster list.

```
def mergeClusters(newCluster, origClusterList):
   newClusterList = []
   for currCluster in origClusterList:
      #Turn lists into sets and look for intersection
      temp = set(newCluster).intersection(set(currCluster))
      if len(temp) == 0:
        #No intersection, so original cluster is unchanged
        newClusterList.append(currCluster)
      else:
        #Merge the two clusters into the newCluster
        newCluster = list(set(newClusterList).union(set(currCluster))

    #Now add the newCluster to the newClusterList
    newclusterList.append(newCluster)
    return newClusterList
```

I'm pretty sure this should work. Assuming it does, then just loop through your new clusters and merge them with your existing clusters:

```
# Assume c1 = existing list of clusters and c2 = new list of clusters
for currCluster in c2:
  c1 = mergeClusters(currCluster, c1)
```

Now, your merged list should be in c1